# Waiting for dojo/request/xhr to finish before returning array from dojo/-base/array.map

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I am modifying the code below which was structured on the example at [Display IdentityTask results in Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/find_popup.html) .

```js
var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams).addCallback(function (response) {
  return arrayUtils.map(response, function (result) {
    var feature = result.feature;
    dojoXhr("/trails/trailPopupUses.action",{
      query:{
        parkName: feature.attributes.PARK_NAME,
        trailName: feature.attributes.TRAIL_ASSOC,
      },
      preventCache: true
    }).then(function(data) {
      useString = data;
      return feature;
    }, function(err) {
      featureResultsContent.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
    });
  });
});

app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
```

My issue is I can't figure out how to insure the `app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);` doesn't execute until the `identifyTask.execute` has finished initializing the `deferred` variable.  I have tried using `.then()` in a couple of places but couldn't get it to work.  The `arrayUtils.map` function returns an array of `features` which is what the `app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);` expects.

Answer (score 0):

I did not make it clear that the `arrayUtils.map` is the `dojo/_base/array.map()` method.  The issue was each iteration of `arrayUtil.map` needed to wait until the data returned from the `dojoXhr` call (which is 'dojo/request/xhr' ) and the `arrayUtils.map` needed to finish before the `app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures()` was called.  My solution was to remove the `return` and use `.then` on the deferred variable.  I also added `sync: true` to the `dojoXhr`.

```
                var featureArray;
            var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);
            deferred.then(function (response) {
                featureArray = arrayUtils.map(response, function (result) {
                    var feature = result.feature;
                    dojoXhr("/trails/trailPopupUses.action",{
                        query:{
                            parkName: feature.attributes.PARK_NAME,
                            trailName: feature.attributes.TRAIL_ASSOC,
                        },
                        preventCache: true,
                        sync: true
                    }).then(function(data){
                        useString = data;
                    });
                    feature.setInfoTemplate(testTemplate);
                    return feature;
                });
                return featureArray;
            }).then(function(featureArray){
                app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(featureArray);
            });
```